# Aggregated view for Display Form for SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-type, list-view, content-query-web-part

Due to my business case, I have a relationship of Person-Position-Certificate lists with existing data. I need to have a Person view that aggregates information from those lists, means I would like to show all certificates with position-related in display form of Person list.

Any ideas? I have research for content type/list definition or web part but I didn't finalize the solution so far.

[image]

Comment: Do you need to make a join?

Comment: Yes that's what I want, but I'm wondering how to apply it the best way, make use of custom content type or web part or anything else?

Answer (score 2):

Just go to your display form, edit the page and add the listview webpart of the other list you want to get data from. Edit the properties of this listview and add a webpart connection that connects the listview with the display form. There you can choose which field connects to what.

https://aspblogs.blob.core.windows.net/media/ricardoperes/Windows-Live-Writer/7db2bdec6747_140F3/image_8.png

Now, whenever you open the display form, it will show the items connected to that particular list item from the other list.

Comment: Actually that's not my expectation, we have some logic that needs to be implemented when joining Person-Position-Certificate lists. I updated my question with attachment, hope you fully understand my case.